# Split a string based on char using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to extract the table name from string and move it into a array using shell script.

Input string format:

```
APPNAME_TABLE_NAME_DATE
```

sample input data:

```
AAA_STUDENT_ADDR_12172014
AAA_STUDENT_DEPT_12172014
AAA_STUDENT_SEC_12172014
AAA_STUDENT_LIST_12172014
```

out should be:

```
STUDENT_ADDR
STUDENT_DEPT
STUDENT_SEC
STUDENT_LIST
```

Can any please help me, I am new to shell script :)

Comment: There are several way to do this, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're old-school and need to do this 100% within the shell, look at the definition of the built-in variable $IFS and at the "set" built-in command. Within your read loop, do `IFS=_` , then use "set" to load the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc) with the split components of the line; then build the result string as "$2_$3". (Don't forget to reset IFS.)

If you're new-school, this can be done with the remove-prefix and remove-suffix feature of parameter expansion. Your task is to rip off the first and last columns ("AAA_" and "_12172014"). If your input line is in the variable $line, then

```
ripfirst=${line#*_}
riplast=${ripfirst%_*}
```

That will leave the correct value in $riplast.

If you can use the full power of the Unix or Linux shell environment, this is a trivial use of regular expressions for sed.